# Como usar usar Checkout Básico en Android

Tags: android, mercadopago

Quiero integrar mercadopago en mi app de android studio.

He leído la documentación pero no entiendo como hay que crea una preferencia de pago en mi servidor.

Alguien tiene un ejemplo paso a paso de esta parte?... El resto parece estar bastante claro.

Gracias de antemano.

Henry

Comment: Bienvenido.Henry, te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Henry,

te cuento como hice la parte del servidor (hardcode solo con el fin de llegar a alguna pantalla de mercadopago) pero no tuve exito ya que la función que realizaba el post no reconocía la URL donde yo tenia mi web service.

```
exports.paymentMercadoPago = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
var mercadopago = require('mercadopago');
mercadopago.configure({
access_token: "***acces-token***"});

var preference = {}

var item = {
title: 'titulo',
quantity: 1,
currency_id: 'ARS',
unit_price: 80
}
var payer = {
name: "name",
surname: "surname",
email: "test@gmail.com",
phone: {
  area_code: "",
  number: 674351766
  },
identification: {
  type: "DNI",
  number: "123456789"
  },
address: {
  street_name: "Subida Ana María Gonzales",
  street_number:  1,
  zip_code: "18101"
  }
}
preference.payer = payer
preference.items = [item]

mercadopago.preferences.create(preference).then(function (data) {
// Do Stuff...
response.send(data);

}).catch(function (error) {
// Do Stuff...
response.send("Error en mercadopago.preferences.create(preference): " + error)
});

});
```

Cuando le hacia un post a la url que tenia esta función, recibía un json con el status 201 que es "preferencia creada" si mal no recuerdo. El problema estaba en la función del sdk de android, que no reconoce mi url.

Por favor, si logras hacer algún avance con la implementación en Android, te agradecería que me comentes como hacerlo.

Saludos, Xavier.